# MAMP Pro won't start even after reinstalling

Tags: mamp

My mac froze earlier today and I forced it to reboot (involving several force quits and eventually holding the power button). After it started up, everything worked except MAMP Pro. When it starts, it doesn't report any errors but just hangs on starting MySQL, with a spinner next to it indefinitely.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail. However, regular MAMP works just fine. I've deleted and reinstalled /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP Pro several times, but maybe there's other files I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by overwriting /etc/apache2/httpd.conf with /etc/apache2/httpd.conf~original

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem tonight.

The reason was that I had created a hostname, but forgot to assign it to a disk location before I clicked ***Apply***.

Amazingly, once you do this, there is no way to actually correct your mistake - it hangs every time you start up, and you never get the option to fix the disk location.

The solution is to remove the entry manually from the MAMP settings plist.

1. Quit MAMP Pro
2. Open `~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/settings.plist`
3. Find the `<dict>` entry that contains your incorrect host - you'll see this inside the XML:

   ```
   <key>serverName</key>
   <string>yourhostname</string>
   ```
4. Delete the entire `<dict>...</dict>` node that contains your hostname missing the disk location and save the file
5. Re-open MAMP Pro

You should be back in business.

For future avoidance of this, it's best to open MAMP Preferences and uncheck ***Allow apply when disk location of a host isn't valid***

Comment: Unbelievable, this just happened to me. I created a host and forgot to assign a disk location, so I stopped MAMP, and mysql hung. So I tried quitting, reopening, restarting, etc... Nothing worked, no message in logs. Thank god I found this, what a strange bug, it should be addressed by appsolute. (note - using Lion 10.7.2)

Comment: This worked. Thank you. This happened after I upgraded to version 4.1 I had two website with directories that didn't exist. I couldn't delete them in the host manager nor the .plist file. I ended up creating two empty folders and then the server started up correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

simply run this on terminal 
     killall -9 mysqld

Answer (score 0):

I added a vhost with an underscore in it's name just before this problem occurred.

After replacing the underscore with a dash by manually editing ~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/settings4.plist everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Mamp Pro 6 (updated from version 5 in July 2021) had this same boot problem and the following fixed it...

- **Remove the entire `htdocs` folder out of /Applications/MAMP/ (moved it to my Documents folder)**

Start up MAMP. All working again. Very strange but it worked and none of the other answers here did, so...

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: @Scott upvote the answers that did work. It's more constructive.

Comment: Sorry @benaminhull - you are right... I was so frustrated with MAMP - the support is so difficult to deal with, the program was so unreliable. I had to uninstall (ironically the uninstaller failed to uninstall because it was running and then uninstalled the uninstaller!) I had to reinstall, uninstall and start over again - losing my 40+ virtual hosts I had set up... back to square one.

Comment: No worries @scott. I hear the frustration, and I get it. Hope you get back on track soon.